# Verilog timer design

Tags: verilog

I am trying to design a timer module for a stopwatch that can measure up to 0.01 second.

Here is what I coded:

```
module Timer (
  input MCLK,
  input RUN,
  input RESET,
  output reg [3:0] M10 = 4'b0,   // 0~9
  output reg [3:0] M1 = 4'b0,    // 0~9
  output reg [3:0] S10 = 4'b0,   // 0~5
  output reg [3:0] S1 = 4'b0,    // 0~9
  output reg [3:0] MS100 = 4'b0, // 0~9
  output reg [3:0] MS10 = 4'b0   // 0~9
  );


reg [19:0]  rCnt = 20'h0_0000; 

always @(posedge MCLK)
begin
    if(RESET == 1'b1)
        begin
            M10 = 4'b0;
            M1 = 4'b0;
            S10 = 4'b0;
            S1 = 4'b0;
            MS100 = 4'b0;
            MS10 = 4'b0;
            rCnt = 20'h0_0000;
        end
    else
        begin
            if (RUN == 1'b1)
                begin
                    rCnt <= rCnt + 20'h0_0001;
                    if(rCnt >= 20'h2710)
                        begin
                            rCnt <= 20'h0_0000; 
                            MS10<=MS10+4'b1;
                            if (MS10 == 4'b1001)
                                begin
                                    MS10<=4'b0;
                                    MS100<=MS100+4'b1;
                                    if (MS100 == 4'b1001)
                                        begin
                                            MS100<=4'b0;
                                            S1<=S1+4'b1;
                                            if (S1 == 4'b1001)
                                                begin
                                                    S1<=4'b0;
                                                    S10<=S10+4'b1;
                                                    if (S10 == 4'b0101)
                                                        begin
                                                            S10<=4'b0;
                                                            M1<=M1+4'b1;
                                                            if (M1 == 4'b1001)
                                                                begin
                                                                    M1<=4'b0;
                                                                    M10<=M10+4'b1;
                                                                    if (M10 == 4'b1001)
                                                                        begin
                                                                            M10 <= 4'b1001;
                                                                            M1 <= 4'b1001;
                                                                            S10 <= 4'b1001;
                                                                            S1 <= 4'b1001;
                                                                            MS100 <= 4'b1001;
                                                                            MS10 <= 4'b1001;
                                                                        end
                                                                end
                                                        end
                                                end
                                        end             
                                end
                        end
                end

        end
end     

endmodule
```

From what I know about Verilog syntax, writing `if` without `else` can cause unwanted latch.

Do I have to code `else` to every single `if` sentence to prevent latches from being created?

I'd appreciate it if you could give me advice about this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’re using a clocked (sequential) block with non blocking assignments there’s no way latches can be inferred.

More about inferred latches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459413/what-is-inferred-latch-and-how-it-is-created-when-it-is-missing-else-statement-i#22464091

Your code could be a lot simpler. You just need counters for h/m/s digits that test for overflow at sexagesimal (base-60) boundaries. That’s like six conditional assigns.

Or you could count ticks and convert to h/m/s for display using an algorithm, which is what most computers do. Probably too complicated for a stopwatch however.

Anyway, code!

```
module main;
reg MCLK, RESET, RUN;
wire [3:0] h1,h0,m0,s0,t1,t0;
wire [2:0] m1,s1;

// DUT instance
stopwatch u_stopwatch(
.MCLK(MCLK),
.RESET(RESET),
.RUN(RUN),
.h1(h1),.h0(h0),
.m1(m1),.m0(m0),
.s1(s1),.s0(s0),
.t1(t1),
.t0(t0)
);

// test bench
reg [31:0] count = 3600;

initial 
    begin
      $display("Hello, World");

        #10; RESET = 0; MCLK = 0; RUN = 1;
        #10 MCLK = 1; # 10 MCLK = 0;
        #10; RESET = 1;
        #10 MCLK = 1; # 10 MCLK = 0;
        #10; RESET = 0; RUN = 1;
       while (count > 0)
       begin
           repeat (100)  // 10ms ticks per second
           begin
                #10 MCLK = 1; # 10 MCLK = 0;
           end
           
            $display(h1,h0,":",m1,m0,":",s1,s0,".",t1,t0);
            count = count -1;
        end
      $finish ;
    end
    
endmodule

module stopwatch (
    input MCLK, RESET, RUN,
    // time format: hh:mm:ss:tt, 10ms per tick
    output reg [3:0] h1,h0, m0,s0, t1,t0,  // 0..9 (4 bits)
    output reg [2:0] m1,s1                  // 0..5 (3 bits)
    );

// carry-chain for counters
assign ci = RUN ? 1 : 0;    // carry-in
assign t0_co = (t0 == 9) && ci; // carry-out
assign t1_co = (t1 == 9) && t0_co;
assign s0_co = (s0 == 9) && t1_co;
assign s1_co = (s1 == 5) && s0_co;
assign m0_co = (m0 == 9) && s1_co;
assign m1_co = (m1 == 5) && m0_co;
assign h0_co = (h0 == 9) && m1_co;
assign h1_co = (h1 == 9) && h0_co;

always @(posedge MCLK or posedge RESET)
begin

    if(RESET)  // asynchronous reset
    begin
            h1 <= 0;
            h0 <= 0;
            m1 <= 0;
            m0 <= 0;
            s1 <= 0;
            s0 <= 0;
            t1 <= 0;
            t0 <= 0;
    end
    else  // synchonous count up, controlled by RUN signal (via ci)
    begin
        t0 <= (t0_co) ? 0 : t0 + ci;
        t1 <= (t1_co) ? 0 : t1 + t0_co;
        s0 <= (s0_co) ? 0 : s0 + t1_co;
        s1 <= (s1_co) ? 0 : s1 + s0_co;
        m0 <= (m0_co) ? 0 : m0 + s1_co;
        m1 <= (m1_co) ? 0 : m1 + m0_co;
        h0 <= (h0_co) ? 0 : h0 + m1_co;
        h1 <= (h1_co) ? 0 : h1 + h0_co;
    end

end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thx for your advice @hacktastical. My purpose was to use less HW resources as possible. What can i do to reduce FFs and gates??

Comment: Ultimately you need as many flops as you have counter bits. As far as complexity, expressing the behavior clearly and letting synthesis do its job will give optimal results.

Comment: That said, for a slow counter like this, you have the option of using a ripple counter approach. This takes the same number of flops but fewer gates.

Comment: The code you posted was really helpful Thx. I know that ripple counter works Asynchronously but your code seems like Synchronous is this right?

Comment: like a ripple counter with FF at the ouput.

Comment: Yes, my code is a sync counter. A  ripple counter uses the FF ‘q’ output to clock the next one. You need then to create two counter types: mod-10 and mod-6, then connect them in series. Each counter needs just one 3-input gate.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly using non-blocking ('<=') assignments in an always @  (posedge... ) block so flip-flops will be created for M10 et al.

No additional latches are required to maintain the previous value in case nothing is assigned, so none will be inferred. It's not a potential issue here.